# Max Date for multiple criteria

Tags: excel, criteria, maxdate

[image]

I need a formula in Column H that only gets the value corresponding to the greatest date - provided value in B is equal to Value in C and appears together more than once. (as shown in the picture)

tried using some variation of the Max date function

| A | B | C | StartDateTime | EndDateTime | DurationinMin | Date | Formula Needed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 324 | 235062-22-001 | CLEANING | 4/4/2023 1:12 | 4/4/2023 1:36 | 23.09 | 4/4/2023 |  |
| 324 | 235062-22-001 | CLEANING | 4/5/2023 0:11 | 4/5/2023 0:18 | 7.15 | 4/5/2023 |  |
| 324 | 235062-22-001 | CLEANING | 4/5/2023 1:33 | 4/5/2023 1:57 | 23.03 | 4/5/2023 |  |
| 324 | 235062-22-001 | CLEANING | 4/5/2023 17:35 | 4/5/2023 17:59 | 23.97 | 4/5/2023 |  |
| 324 | 235062-22-001 | CLEANING | 4/5/2023 21:06 | 4/5/2023 21:59 | 53.26 | 4/5/2023 |  |
| 324 | 235062-22-001 | CLEANING | 4/6/2023 0:12 | 4/6/2023 0:55 | 43.15 | 4/6/2023 | 43.15 |
| 324 | 235062-22-001 | WASHING | 4/12/2023 11:23 | 4/12/2023 12:49 | 85.56 | 4/12/2023 | 85.56 |
| 324 | 235062-22-001 | PEALING | 4/13/2023 5:03 | 4/13/2023 6:01 | 57.82 | 4/13/2023 | 57.82 |

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have?

Comment: You should paste your sample as text not as image, use tools like this https://tableconvert.com/

Comment: Version 2108...

Comment: " value in B is equal to Value in C " does not make sense, please clarify or fix

Comment: In H2, `=If($G2=maxifs($G$2:$G$9,$C$2:$C$9,$C2),$F2,"")`  It puts a blank string if it does not qualify, and the value if it does qualify.

Comment: If B appears multiple times in range and C appears multiple times in range in the same combination in tandem, then only show value of F which corresponds to the max date in G. For eg . 235062-22-001 (value in B) is in department CLEANING for 4/5 date and 4/6 but only take into account duration for 4/6 (greatest date) and others will show 0. We only need 43.15 i.e duration of the greatest date to show.

Comment: sorry, still not clear for me to help

Comment: Solved using =If($G2=maxifs($G$2:$G$9,$C$2:$C$9,$C2),$F2,"") provided by Chris. Thanks!